# Google Cloud Monitoring storage dashboard not showing Object Count or Object size for bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-stackdriver

I'm trying to see Object Count and Object Size in the Cloud Monitoring dashboard for Cloud Storage. For some buckets, the Object Count and Object size data are not populating. All I'm seeing is "No data is available for the selected time frame".

I've tried different time frames and have waited 24 hours for data to show up. Other buckets in the same project have object count and object size data.

[screen shot of Object Count missing data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnKlX.png)

Comment: same issue for me. Object Count is 0 when Total Bytes is displayed in the same dashboard. I works when value is displayed alone

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to an internal issue with the Google Cloud Storage that occurred throughout the time you opened this question.

This was internally fixed and your metrics should now show the correct information.

Please let me know if it still doesn't work.